# 80% of Website Traffic coming from Just one Town in USA - Strange?

Tags: google-analytics, robots.txt, botattack, web-traffic, fraud-detection

For the last month, 80% of my total traffic was coming from just one Town in the USA. Here are the attributes:

1. It is one of the richest towns in California in USA which defies logic since I run a website for coupons.
2. The bounce rate is not 100%. It is around 80%. I read on this forum and it talked about how the bounce rate should be very close to 100% if it is a bot.
3. Almost 98% of visitors from this town show up as new visitors.
4. Around 20% of this traffic shows up as coming from Stumble Upon with a Bounce Rate of 57%. The other 80% shows up as coming DIRECT to website. (Hardly unlikely since we just started the website).
5. 50% of Visitors are using Chrome, 30% Firefox and 20% Safari.

Can anyone tell me how to check if all this traffic from one town is real or fake? I am concerned that DIRECT Traffic is highly unlikely since this is a very competitive market and we just got started.

Comment: If I may ask, what town or city are we talking about specifically?

Comment: Have you tried searching something like "a lot of traffic from TOWNNAME". You are probaly not the first.

Comment: It is Beverly Hills..

Comment: StumbleUpon send tons of bots to your site once it's in their network. Whilst 20% of this traffic shows StumbleUpon as the referrer (this will only be from clicks on links) - a large majority of the rest of the Beverley Hills traffic will be SU bots.

Comment: Hi zigojacko: So it would be fair to say that the SU bots traffic is useless? Is there a way that i can filter it out in google analytics?

Comment: You don't want to just filter them out in reports, if they are really useless to you and your site, you want to block them completely. But first, be sure that they are useless.

Comment: You can filter out the requests or create a custom segment. The filter is good if the location (here: Beverley Hills) does not change very often. Google for "google analytics filter" to find some tuts.

Answer (score 1):

If it is natural, then no issues. But Bounce rate should not exceed 40% and above.

Comment: Acceptable bouncerate depends on the type of website you got, and it's genre. I have 50% for a webshop, which is pretty ok.

Answer (score 1):

Enable logging of your visitors in your site , and check whether they are coming from different ipaddress or same. If they are not from same IP then most probably they are genuine traffic